# 2 results from the case directive

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Why in this query I get two results using case?
I thought that after the first condition is met, a break follows and the second is not checked at all

```
select KOD from ap_magazyny mag where 1 =
    case 
    when (value1 like 'ZZ%' and mag.KOD like (select SUBSTR(value1,INSTR(value1,'/',1)+1,3) from dual)) then 1
    when (atrybut_t01 = value2 AND rownum = 1) then 1
    else 0
    end
```

Result like
[image]

Comment: You have two rows that match the conditions.  What is the issue?

Comment: case operates on a column level.

Comment: Is possible to break case statement after match to first condition ?

Comment: These are two seperate KOD that match the condition ZG0 and ZG1

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph
In date like 

`select KOD from ap_magazyny mag where 1 =
    case 
    when (atrybut_t01 = 5902596218362  AND rownum = 1) then 1
    when ('ZZT/ZG1/00023/07/2021' like 'ZZ%' and mag.KOD like (select SUBSTR('ZZT/ZG1/00023/07/2021',INSTR('ZZT/ZG1/00023/07/2021','/',1)+1,3) from dual)) then 1
    else 0
    end`

Are only 1  match value in first condition its ZG1

Comment: Why do you have 2 cases that return the same results instead of using OR?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rownum=1 to limit the results.

```
select * from (
    select KOD 
      from ap_magazyny mag 
     where 1 = case when (value1 like 'ZZ%' 
                         and mag.KOD like (select SUBSTR(value1,INSTR(value1,'/',1)+1,3) 
                                             from dual)
                                           ) then 1
                    when (atrybut_t01 = value2 AND rownum = 1) then 1
                    else 0
               end
    order by case when (value1 like 'ZZ%' 
                         and mag.KOD like (select SUBSTR(value1,INSTR(value1,'/',1)+1,3) 
                                             from dual)
                                           ) then 1
                    when (atrybut_t01 = value2 AND rownum = 1) then 2
               end
)x
where rownum=1
```

Comment: Using rownum it gets a random result depending on which result the database puts on top. Unfortunately, the order of the results does not follow the  case order

Comment: supposing only value2 results in two entries what should be the order

Comment: updated the answer to be ordered by the conditions that are met first

Answer (score 1):

I hope my example will help:

```
with cte as (select case when id = 1 then
                       1
                  else 
                       2
                  end A 
           from test
           where rownum = 1) 
select *
from  test
join cte on test.id = cte.A
```

You will need to connect it to something because 1 will always be 1 and you will get all the results from the table test.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=014db2816fde8e986ae9cd7cb0474722)